# Python can not read CSV file

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a file but the file path is having an issue.

Here is the line of the code:

data = pd.read_csv(C:/Users/pythonmonkey/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Projects/'GlobalLandTemperaturesByMajorCity.csv')

Here is the error:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone please help me find out what's wrong with line?

I tried to change the "" to "/"

I extracted the file path directly from the file properties, and I have double and triple check the spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to specify the quote around the whole path.

```
file_path = "C:/Users/pythonmonkey/OneDrive/Desktop/Python Projects/GlobalLandTemperaturesByMajorCity.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: Tried and it says FileNotFoundError

Very odd

Comment: Can you copy paste the path in your explorer window and tell me if it opens?

Comment: Yeah, the file would be downloaded

Comment: Ahh okay I see the file is on onedrive. You have first to download it on you local pc in order to open it that way

Comment: Or you can download it with python or use some library for it to fetch it

Comment: Please don’t forget to upvote and accept. Since the original question was answered :)